# SentinelOne, issue with Keylogger switch-off

Tags: keylogger

I am using SentinelOne for DLP (data lost prevention) and I thought that I switched-off Keylogger, but I still see in logs information such as "KeyloggerDetectionUtil.h".

[image]

Do you know, how can I totally switch-off keylogger in SentinelOne?